# numberOfSectionsInTableView not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In my ViewController, i have an UITableView and these methods :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(self.mQuoteObjects.count > 0){
        return 1
    }
    return 0

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfSectionsInTableView section: Int) -> Int {
    let nbItem = self.mQuoteObjects.count
    return nbItem

}
```

Method "numberOfRowsInSection" is correctly called, but "numberOfSectionsInTableView" is never called.

What have i missed?

You can respond in Obj-c

Comment: Begin typing "tableview" on a newline and you'll see all of the available tableView functions if the class has the UITableViewDelegate to avoid mismatched function names.

Comment: @DCGoD yeah all except the one they need `numberOfSectionsInTableView `

Comment: Then simply type, numberOf... and it'll autocomplete that as well...

Comment: i have do this + a breakpoint in this method, i have tried with a fixed Int too :

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name of the method is not correct. It should be `numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:)`.

See the [UITableViewDataSource protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:).

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.mQuoteObjects.count
}
```

Comment: "func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {}" is correct. Again, use autocomplete to determine the current proper function by beginning to type the function name.

Comment: You saved me, so "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfSectionsInTableView section: Int)" is useless in swift". I have a delay of 10 minutes to accept answer. TY

Comment: Useless in swift and objc.. looks like `numberOfSectionsInTableView` has been used [since iOS 2.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:)

Comment: What exactly is "useless" here Wezly? And no, the exact function syntax has not been the same since 2.0 and is exactly the problem he experienced. Autocomplete the functions people. Use the IDE!

Answer (score 7):

If any one is Using **SWIFT 5**

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2
    }
```

Comment: Merry Christmas

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a **bug in Swift 5** about inheritance, for example:

If you have a class that implements **UITableViewDataSource** but, does not implement **numberOfSections**, only in the subclass,
this function will **never be called**. You need to declare this function in this class and **override** in the subclass.

For more information about:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115579
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10257

Answer (score 0):

The method name is wrong

try this:

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.mQuoteObjects.count
 }
```

Comment: `override` is only necessary when subclassing `UITableViewController`

Comment: Now your answer is just a duplicate of Macros's - best to delete.